# CSS transform and box-shadow on hover

Tags: css, material-ui, transform, card

I have card component using material UI. The card is transforming on hover and there should appear shadow on the card too. But when i put the box-shadow shadow appears on the box before transforming, and there is white space between the transformed card and the shadow. How can i fix this?

```
const CardStyle = styled(Card)`
  background: red;
  transition: transform 50ms;
  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.02) perspective(0px);
    box-shadow: ${({ theme }) => theme.shadows[4]};
  }
`;
```

The same output in other way:

```
:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02) perspective(0px);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(60, 60, 93, 0.33)
}
```

Comment: What is `theme.shadows[4]`? Is there some x, y offset?

Comment: yes, that is offset for shadows dimension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include a transition for your `box-shadow` if I'm understanding your intent right.

```css
div {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  border: green 5px dashed;
  background: red;
  transition: transform .5s, box-shadow 1s;
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02) perspective(0px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(255,0,0,.7);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```